# XSLT-go into first child then loop thru its children and output attribute names

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to XSLT. I'm trying to transform xml data to tab-delimited text file. I really appreciate your help in advance.

XML Data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xml_extract version="V1.2">
    <tables>
        <table name="TAB_1">
            <row>
                <columns>
                    <column name="ID" type="-5">1001410</column>
                    <column name="EXT_ID" type="-5">1001410</column>
                    <column name="LANG" type="12">en</column>
                    <column name="NAME" type="12">B10060601</column>
                </columns>
            </row>
            <row>
                <columns>
                    <column name="ID" type="-5">1001412</column>
                    <column name="EXT_ID" type="-5">1001412</column>
                    <column name="LANG" type="12">en</column>
                    <column name="NAME" type="12">B10141005</column>
                </columns>
            </row>
            <row>
                <columns>
                    <column name="ID" type="-5">1001414</column>
                    <column name="EXT_ID" type="-5">1001414</column>
                    <column name="LANG" type="12">en</column>
                    <column name="NAME" type="12">B10438001</column>
                </columns>
            </row>
        </table>
    </tables>
</xml_extract>
```

After XSLT transformation, I'd like below output in tab-delimited TEXT (not XML):

```
ID  EXT_ID  LANG    NAME
1001410 1001410 en  B10060601
1001412 1001412 en  B10141005
1001414 1001414 en  B10438001
```

Thanks in advance,

The hard part is to output column headers. Besides hard code column headers, I tried below.

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!-- Headers -->
        <xsl:for-each select="//columns[1]/column">
            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
            <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text> <!-- tab delimited -->
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text> <!-- new line -->
        <!-- Data -->
        <xsl:for-each select="//columns/column">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="not(@name='NAME')">
                    <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text> <!-- tab delimited -->
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="@name='NAME'">
                    <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text> <!-- new line -->
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
ID  EXT_ID  LANG    NAME    ID  EXT_ID  LANG    NAME    ID  EXT_ID  LANG    NAME    
1001410 1001410 en  B10060601
1001412 1001412 en  B10141005
1001414 1001414 en  B10438001
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  SO is a very useful place, but don't confuse it with a hire-a-programmer-for-free site.  You're much more likely to get good responses here if you show what you have tried, in a form that allows others to reproduce the problem.  Not showing your work gives the impression you haven't done any and just want others to do your work for you.  There is good advice on asking effective questions in the [SO help files](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `xsl:for-each` to this to get the column headers

```
<xsl:for-each select="(//columns)[1]/column">
```

Your previous expression is actually getting the first occurrence of every `columns` under each of their parent elements. That is to say, for every `row` element, it will get the first `columns` element before it.